# How to get store data from Ext.grid.Panel after its done rendering

Tags: extjs

I have to get my Grid column's data to make some decision and fill some data in some inputboxes once Grid is done rendering. But I am unable to fetch Grid Store.

I know how to get Store data

`var store = Ext.getCmp('USER_GRID').getStore();`

But I am little confused, where to put this piece of code.

One way to put this in `renderer: function(value, rowIndex, colIndex)` of column of grid.

I also tried

```
         Ext.create( 'Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id:'USER_GRID',
            store: myStore,
            columns : [{...my columns....}]
            listeners: {
                render:function(){
                    var store = Ext.getCmp('USER_GRID').getStore();
                }
            },
```

But here also I am getting store as blank.

I also tried putting the same in

```
tbar: [{
        xtype : 'textfield',
        id:'TOTAL_USERS',
        fieldLabel : 'Total Users',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(field){
                var store = Ext.getCmp('USER_GRID').getStore();
            });
        }
     }
},
```

Its blank here too.

Could you please help?

**EDIT:**
Thanks @Sergey but I don't know why I am not getting `myStore` in my `afterrender` method. But I am getting the same in your fiddle example.

I used another way to fulfill my requirement.

```
dockedItems: [
  {
     xtype: 'toolbar',
     dock: 'top',
     items: [{
           xtype: 'label',
           text: 'Live Users:'
        },{
           xtype: 'displayfield',
           id: 'TOTAL_LIVE_USERS',
           value: '0'
        }
     ]
 }
],
```

//This is Column Code . After every render call I am increasing value by 1 to make a final count.

```
{text: "Licence Tpye", width: 100, dataIndex: 'licenceType', sortable: true,
        renderer: function(value, rowIndex, colIndex){
        var val = parseInt(Ext.getCmp("TOTAL_LIVE_USERS").value);

        if(value == 'Live'){
            Ext.getCmp('TOTAL_LIVE_USERS').setValue(val + 1);
        }

        return value;
    }
 }
```

Please suggest, if its a wrong or correct way to do the same. Any harm??

Comment: Are u using Ext6? If yes, please try `boxready` event. The afterrender event is fired too early. You can also get a store by assigning it a storeId and using `Ext.getStore(storeId)`

Comment: It's blank because the store hasn't loaded the data yet when the grid just finished rendering probably. Maybe you want to attach a listener to store's load event.

Answer (score 1):

Since data in your inputboxes depends on store data you have to listen store load event (I guess each time your store is loaded you have to update data).

Before store is loaded you can set those inputboxes as disabled or show that it is not ready yet in some other way.

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13vo) to illustrate how you can listen to store load event and update grid toolbar fields.